# What is the pytest command to test one or some of the pytest.mark.parametrize parameters?

Tags: pytest

I have a unit test function similar to the following. How can I run pytest for only one of these parameters instead of 4 parameters?

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_plot_shap_values", [get_binary_data_and_with_many_category,
    get_multiclass_data_and_with_many_category,
    get_binary_data_and_without_category,
    get_multiclass_data_and_without_category
    ])
def tests_plot_shap_values(test_plot_shap_values):
    ...
    ...
```

I tried `pytest test_plot_shap_values.py::tests_plot_shap_values::get_binary_data_and_with_many_category` but it gives me an ERROR: not found

Answer (score 1):

You can add ids to the parameters and then use the `-k` argument to filter them.

In your code:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_plot_shap_values", [get_binary_data_and_with_many_category,
    get_multiclass_data_and_with_many_category,
    get_binary_data_and_without_category,
    get_multiclass_data_and_without_category
    ], ids=["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"])
```

Then `pytest -k "tests_plot_shap_values and id2"`.

See more at https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to test multiple IDs? `pytest -k "test_plot_shap_values.py and id1 and id2"` doesn't work

Comment: You can try to do `or`. 

Another alternative is to have a common substring, for example, name the ids: `get_binary_many`, `get_binary_without`, `get_multiclass_many`, `get_multiclass_without`, then you can do `pytest -k "tests_plot_shap_values and get_binary"`

Answer (score 0):

What about running it like this? `pytest test_file_name.py::test_test_name[your_params]`

i.e. file name, then test name, then param values in square brackets

Comment: It gives me `zsh: no matches found: pytest test_file_name.py::test_test_name[your_params]`. Same if [your_params] part is replaced with [id1], as suggested by @PeterK

Comment: Are you sure you got your test file names & test names correctly? Also pay attention to paths (those are tricky, I know)

so basically like this, i.e. that last part is in square brackets; and if there's some folder that the tests are located in, make sure it's in path (or that you're located in that folder while running the test)
`pytest test_plot_shap_values.py::tests_plot_shap_values[get_binary_data_and_with_many_category]`